k-twin prime pairs
In connection with the Zhang/Maynard/Tao/Polymath8 developments on $k$-twin primes (let's use this term for a pair of primes at distance $k$), I have a naive question: it is known currently that there are infinitely many $k$-twin prime pairs for some $k\leq 246$.  But is there any specific $k$ (without restriction on size) for which it is known that there are infinitely many $k$-twin pairs?  If not, can one trim down the number of values of $k$ ensuring infinitely many such twins (for one of the values of $k$), to fewer than 123?

For those interested, I checked with ChatGPT that the positive differences among the elements of $${0, 4, 6, 16, 30, 34, 36, 46, 48, 58, 60, 64, 70, 78, 84, 88, 90, 94, 100, 106,
108, 114, 118, 126, 130, 136, 144, 148, 150, 156, 160, 168, 174, 178, 184,
190, 196, 198, 204, 210, 214, 216, 220, 226, 228, 234, 238, 240, 244, 246}$$ are indeed all the even numbers from $2$ to $246$. The above $50$-element set is used to establish the quoted result $k\leq 246$, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897

I added "Polymath8" to your first sentence as $k\leq 246$ is a result of the Polymath8 team.

@GHfromMO, Are you saying that currently one cannot trim down the number of values of $k$ below 123?

I am saying that there seems to be no cheap way to exclude some $k\leq 246$. If $\mathcal{H}$ denotes the $50$-element set in my previous comment, then what Polymath8 really proved is that infinitely many shifts $n+\mathcal{H}$ contain at least two primes. That is, there are two distinct elements $h,h'\in\mathcal{H}$ such that the equation $p-p'=h-h'$ has infinitely many solutions in primes. If the differences $h-h'$ skipped an even number from $2$ to $246$, then we would be down to at most $122$ values of $k$, but this is not the case. Of course anyone can try to improve on Polymath8.

@GHfromMO, thanks for the clarification.  You might as well add a link to Polymath8.

@GH, I don't know much about the techniques involved, but I imagine that if one modifies the 50-element set you mentioned by skipping a few small numbers and adding a few large ones, one might get another set of differences $k$ where one is guaranteed to find infinitely many $k$-twin primes.  Now let $A$ be the set of diffences obtained as in Polymath8, and let $B$ be the set of differences obtained from the modified set.  Then we know that a magic $k$ occurs in either the intersection or the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.  Is there any chance this might get us below 123?

Polymath8 (following Maynard and Tao) proves a general result of the following flavor. If $\mathcal{H}$ is a "large" set of integers that does not represent all residue classes modulo any $m>1$, then infinitely many translates of $\mathcal{H}$ contain "many" primes. If the admissible set $\mathcal{H}$ has size at least $50$, then infinitely many translates of $\mathcal{H}$ contain two primes. So for any admissible set $\mathcal{H}$ of size at least $50$, one of the positive differences among the elements of $\mathcal{H}$ occurs infinitely often as a difference between two prime numbers.

Continued from the previous remark: I am not sure if there is an admissible set of size $50$ with fewer than $123$ positive differences among its elements. I guess that there is no such admissible set, but I have not proved this and will not attempt to prove this. The second Polymath8 paper is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897

The answer to the first question is no. If one can prove for any positive integer $k$ that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p + 2k$ is also prime, then one can likely refine and apply whatever techniques used to obtain such a result to the case $k = 1$: i.e., the actual twin primes.
The reason is that there is a gaping chasm between results of the Maynard-Zhang type, which asserts that for some admissible set $\mathcal{H} = \{h_1, \cdots, h_k\}$ of cardinality at least $3$ and diameter $C = \max_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} |h_i - h_j| \geq 6$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ with the property that there are at least two indices $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ with $n + h_i, n + h_j$ both prime, and an actual twin-prime type theorem: this gaping chasm has a name, which is the Parity Barrier.
The former type of result can be obtained with a sufficiently powerful sieve that only takes as an input some sort of Type I information, which in the case of primes comes from the Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem (unconditionally) or the Elliott-Halberstam Conjecture (conditionally, but much more powerful). Selberg showed that Type I information can never produce primes on its own, since the set of positive integers with exactly two distinct prime factors behave identically under such a sieve as the primes themselves, yet obviously contains no primes. This is known as the Parity Barrier.
To beat the parity barrier, one would have to have some sort of non-trivial Type II information. The most comprehensive treatment of the interaction between Type I information and Type II information with respect to a prime-detecting sieve is the recent work of Ford and Maynard: On the theory of prime producing sieves. However, it is known that non-trivial Type II information (or bilinear sum estimates) can be used to produce primes since the seminal work of Friedlander and Iwaniec: Asymptotic sieve for primes.

I am a bit puzzled by your reliance on Selberg as in "Selberg showed that Type I information can never produce primes on its own, since the set of positive integers with exactly two distinct prime factors behave identically under such a sieve as the primes themselves, yet obviously contains no primes."  The reason I am puzzled is that in the present case of Zhang/Maynard/Tao, the "Type I information" does seem to produce infinitely many $k$-twin prime pairs, albeit for an indeterminate $k$ (below 246).   Also, do you have a link discussing the "Parity Barrier"?

@MikhailKatz I am not sure how familiar you are with modern sieve theory. By now we have very strong theorems of the shape "infinitely many integers with at most $k$ many prime factors" in various contexts. This is how one obtains that there are infinitely many prime pairs within a bounded gap: one shows that for a given admissible set $H$ that there are infinitely many $n$ such that the TOTAL number of prime factors among $n + h_1, \cdots, n + h_k$ is not too large, and that many of them have to have a lot of prime factors, forcing some of them to be prime.

Thanks for the clarification.  Are the 123 differences of Polymath8 guaranteed to include only one difference $k$ such that there are infinitely many $k$-twin pairs, or perhaps more than one?  If only one, can one improve the ratio (number of differences)/(number of successful $k$'s) to be better than 123, by choosing a different starting set (than the 50-element set listed in user GH's comment above)?

@MikhailKatz the answer is no. There is really no precision embedded in the type of sieve used here; that's kind of the point. For all we know it is often the case that for most of the $n$'s produced in the sieve, almost all of the terms $n + h_1, \cdots, n + h_k$ are prime, but this cannot be proved from the sieve alone. A major hurdle is that no one has yet come up with any plausible strategy to obtain Type II bounds for such set-ups. Any progress could lead to the resolution of "binary" problems such as Goldbach's conjecture and twin prime conjecture.

So I was thinking that if one starts with a set $B$ different from the 50-member set $A={0,4,6,\ldots,246}$ such that $B$ also results in a difference set containing a successful $k$, then either the intersection of the corresponding difference sets will contain a successful $k$, or their symmetric difference will contain a pair of successful $k$s.  Naively it seems that this might lead to a situation where we know that there is a difference set with ratio less than 123.  Would that be unlikely?
